# How to properly use Firebase from a foreground service in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have written an android app that uses firebase anonymous authentication and writes to the firebase database from a foreground service. I am using `onDisconnect().removeValue()` to cleanup data created by my app when the websocket is closed. When a user is actively engaging with the app, the `onDisconnect()` call triggers as expected (meaning my security rules are OK). However, when the foreground service is left running for a long period of time (e.g. overnight, screen turns off, etc.), the `onDisconnect()` call is never triggered again. The app continues to function upon wakeup (communicating with firebase server, etc.) but when it comes time to close the app (following a period of idle time), it seems that the `onDisconnect()` call has been lost somehow.

I have read that anonymous authentication sessions are quietly refreshed by the firebase SDK every hour. Is it possible this is happening in the activity (and being killed by the OS, but keeping the foreground service alive), therefore causing the server to discard the callback to `onDisconnect`? If so, can this functionality be preserved within the foreground service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has had a bug recently (not sure if it's been fixed), where when it reauthenticates every hour, it loses the onDisconnect() because it no longer has permission to alter that node. This then causes the duplicate.

Some possible solutions:

1. Attach a timestamp and check if the last timestamp is over an hour, and if it is, then delete it when adding the new one.
2. Remove authentication requirements for writing in the node to keep track of the disconnects (this would not be secure though, depends on your needs).

Here are some more alternatives, and a better explanation of the problem from a member of the Firebase team: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228422/user-presence-and-authentication).

Comment: Thanks @Aubtin. It's good to know that its not a problem with my code, and that the Firebase team is aware of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Android application processes can live indefinitely.  When the user stops using an app, Android may continue to keep the process alive, in order to make it load faster if and when the user comes back.  You can think of this is an optimization, and you should expect this to happen sometimes.  You shouldn't try to control this behavior - let Android manage this for you.

Your connection to the database is not being closed because the app is still alive and holding on to its connection to the database.  I suggest you track for yourself when the user stops using your app, and force a cleanup at an appropriate time after that, without assuming that Android will ever kill your app's process.